# Use a countdown inside react-hot-toast

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toast

I am trying to use a countdown inside a toast using react-hot-toast but I cannot find the way to make it work properly.

I have tried using my own countdown, using the ract-countdown package, trying to get a timer from react-hot-toast, but with no luck yet.

I am a beginner using react, so maybe it is not that difficult but I am unable to get it. The main problem is to pause all the countdown on hover and start on leave.